# Involutions of Hirzebruch surfaces with finite number of fixed points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, soft-question, fibration

I am looking for a reference that addresses the question of which Hirzebruch surfaces $\mathbb{F}_n$ admit an involution that has only finitely many fixed points (no fixed curves).

Relatedly, I am also looking for information on the question of which blow-ups of Hirzebruch surfaces admit involutions with finitely many fixed points.

---

For some context, the question of which del Pezzo surfaces admit involutions with finite number of fixed points is addressed in Appendix A of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.2936v3.pdf) (it is only possible for $dP_3$ and $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$, the latter also being the Hirzebruch surface $\mathbb{F}_0$). I have not been able to find an analogous analysis for the Hirzebruch surfaces. In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9912208v2.pdf) on p.33 it is claimed without proof that such an involution can be found for $\mathbb{F}_2$, but that this cannot be done for all $\mathbb{F}_r$. Also the case of $\mathbb{F}_1$ is covered by the del Pezzo analysis, since $\mathbb{F}_1$ is isomorphic to $dP_1$.